# jasper print not working error says xml parsing error

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using japer 3.7.6 in my project.Jasper works good locally in my computer.When the same project is hosted in linux server there appears this issue.For some reports jasper is working but in some reports it shows following error :

In Firefox :
[image]

In Chrome:

[image]

My jasper report code is like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="shareDividentReport_np" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isSummaryNewPage="true">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.report.description" value=""/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.652892561983471"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="institutionName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="scheme" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="trxnDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="custName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[custName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="sNo" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="address" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[address]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="accNo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="amount" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="remarks" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="337" y="19" width="215" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="305" y="-1" width="247" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{institutionName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="3" y="2" width="142" height="22"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fund Distribution Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="400" y="41" width="81" height="14"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Transaction Date :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="3" y="41" width="73" height="14"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Scheme Name :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="77" y="41" width="124" height="14"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{scheme}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="481" y="41" width="70" height="14"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{trxnDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="17" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="3" y="1" width="22" height="14"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[#]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="554" height="1"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1" height="16"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="1" y="16" width="554" height="1"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="25" y="0" width="1" height="16"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="131" y="1" width="1" height="16"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="28" y="1" width="106" height="14"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="201" y="1" width="1" height="16"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="204" y="1" width="58" height="14"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Acc No]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="261" y="1" width="1" height="16"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="368" y="1" width="1" height="16"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="554" y="1" width="1" height="16"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="134" y="1" width="68" height="14"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Address]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="262" y="0" width="107" height="17">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="1e3ff973-33f4-46e2-8c61-70a570ebcd40"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Amount]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="370" y="0" width="184" height="17">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="5f9168c6-3ec7-40d1-92ec-fd6608f42808"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Remarks]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="17" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="-1" width="1" height="16" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="25" y="0" width="1" height="16" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="131" y="-1" width="1" height="16" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="201" y="0" width="1" height="16" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="261" y="0" width="1" height="16" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="368" y="0" width="1" height="16" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="554" y="-1" width="1" height="16" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="15" width="554" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="30" y="-1" width="100" height="16">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="737f7de1-b4b4-49bd-8d44-4fa181039ac1"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{custName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="-1" width="25" height="16">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="d6382c06-3ada-460a-9cd4-eb3c7a6404b9"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{sNo}>0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{sNo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="135" y="-1" width="66" height="16">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="18069ac2-9301-4317-b20a-447a97937054"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="202" y="-1" width="56" height="16">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="fb1cc6a9-727b-4827-847a-48952b87e8ba"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{accNo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="262" y="-1" width="101" height="16">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="8a107053-079b-4a12-83ed-5ec9e16a7613"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="373" y="-1" width="181" height="16">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="421fa618-29d6-4861-b625-ffa1e0b8d73a"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{remarks}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>


</jasperReport>
```

Similarly code to print is like this:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint;
    try {
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, params,
                new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lstFundDistReport));

        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getResponse();
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=FundDistReport.pdf");
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, servletOutputStream);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        servletOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have used same code to print different reports in my application.I repeat in local computer every reports are working fine.But same application hosted in Linux server gives such unusual error. Some reports are exported to pdf but majorly this issue appears for others reports.

Comment: and you are sure that lstFundDistReport is not empty?, hence you are passing an empty pdf to the browser

Comment: yes i have checked lstFundDistReport is not empty